# Outlook attachments count showing incorrect number

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I am trying to loop through all the attached items in the selected mail, but the count of attachment is producing absurd value.

```
Sub ABU_out()

Dim olapp As Outlook.Application
Dim olmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim item As Object
Dim olath As Outlook.Attachments




Set olapp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set olmail = olapp.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)


If Not olmail.Attachments.Count = 0 Then

Debug.Print olmail.Attachments.Count

        For Each olath In olmail.Attachments

            If InStr(LCase(olath.FileName), "certificate") Then

                If InStr(LCase(olath.FileName), "endorsement") = 0 Then

                    Debug.Print olath.FileName

                    olath.SaveAsFile "C:\Users\mohit.bansal\Desktop\Automations\ABU\Slips Sample\" & olath.FileName

                End If

            End If

        Next

End If



End Sub
```

Problem occurs when I select a mail with 2 items 'debug.print' says 3 and if the mail has 3 items it says 5. Error comes in olath says its Nothing Not sure what is wrong in the code, I have used the similar code in private events which works smoothly.

Comment: Don't forget that images are also attachments.  I suggest investigating each attachment before dismissing the count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error .... I am declaring olath as outlook.attachments whereas if i declare it as object it works.

Comment: There is an extra s here. Dim olath As Outlook.Attachments